# Check whether list object is null in java

Tags: java, null

I'm checking whether a `List` object is `null` or not using java. But I'm not sure whether it is the optimized way or not.

Here is my code:

```
List<String> listSCBPLNewErrMsgs= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES.split("\\$\\@")));
```

The above line itself throws null pointer exception.

```
if(listSCBPLNewErrMsgs != null) <Right way?>
```

This will get all the values from the config.

Now, tomorrow if I change the config entry, this should not throw an null pointer exception

Comment: `listSCBPLNewErrMsgs` will not be null, since you just instantiated it. It may however have 0 elements.

Comment: And *objects* can't be `null`. Object references, such as the one in `listSCBPLNewErrMsgs`, can be `null`, but not objects. But as Ori said, the one above definitely won't be.

Comment: Are you sure that `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES` is non-null?

Comment: Yes. SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES.. This is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES` is null that code will still fail.

Assuming that `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES` has some value or is empty, the split will return an array of size 0 or more. Changing it to a list from an array will yield either an array with 0 or more elements.

Lastly, the copy constructor will copy the content and assign it to a new list. In all scenarios, unless there is a null pointer on `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES`, the returned list (`listSCBPLNewErrMsgs`) will never be null, at most it will be empty, which can be checked with the `isEmpty()` method call.

As per your comment, if you are getting a `null` pointer on that line, it should be due to the fact that `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES` is null.

Try this:

```
List<String> listSCBPLNewErrMsgs = null;
if(SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES != null) {
    listSCBPLNewErrMsgs= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES.split("\\$\\@")));
}
else {
    listSCBPLNewErrMsgs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Exactly npinti.. List<String> listSCBPLNewErrMsgs= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES.split("\\$\\@"))); This line itself is null

Comment: @Nizam: I have updated my answer. You are doing 3 operations in that line, two of which will *never* return null, at most return an empty collection. However, if you try to split on a null string you will get the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

The `new` operator in Java can **never** return `null`. Neither can [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

What you may want to check, however, is that the list is not empty:

```
if (listSCBPLNewErrMsgs.isEmpty()) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik. I have updated the question, Can you please check.. The instantiate itself is throwing null pointer exception

Comment: @Nizam did you verify that `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES` is not null?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether it is null it is right way (even though it will never be null), however if you simply want to check if list is empty then you should use `isEmpty()` method:

```
if(listSCBPLNewErrMsgs.isEmpty()) {/**/}
```

Comment: I have updated the question, Can you please check.. The instantiate itself is throwing null pointer exception

Comment: I think you forgot the unary boolean operator there '!'

Answer (score 1):

From the looks if your code your listSCBPLNewErrMsgs object won't be null. Test if it is empty using the `listSCBPLNewErrMsgs.isEmpty();`

Comment: I have updated the question, Can you please check.. The instantiate itself is throwing null pointer exception

Comment: Then check if the SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES object is null

Answer (score 1):

If `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES` is nulll that will throw a NPE exception indeed since you will be using the `split` method on `null`.

You can first check if that's not null:

```
if (SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES != null) {
      //Instantiate list
      //Optional isEmpty check
}
```

You will first check if `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES` is not null

Then you can instantiate your list and perform an optional `isEmpty` check on the new list.

Comment: I have updated the question, Can you please check.. The instantiate itself is throwing null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to add null check for `SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES`.

```
if (SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES != null && !SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES.isEmpty()) {
```

---

In your declaration, list can not be null as your are doing `new ArrayList<String>`.
So no need to worry about null pointer exception.

---

If you wish to check for empty list.
Then you can try [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty%28%29) method.

```
if (SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES != null && !SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES.isEmpty()) {
    List<String> listSCBPLNewErrMsgs = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES.split("\\$\\@")));
    if (!listSCBPLNewErrMsgs.isEmpty()) {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES != null)
  List<String> listSCBPLNewErrMsgs= new ArrayList<String>Arrays.asList(SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES.split("\\$\\@")));
```

No Need of `listSCBPLNewErrMsgs != null` as everyone said

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES is null or empty

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(SCBPL_NEW_ERRORMESSAGES))
```

You have to check both whether the list is null/empty or not. So I prefer

```
if(listSCBPLNewErrMsgs != null && !listSCBPLNewErrMsgs.isEmpty()) {
}
```